# In PHP 5.2 why is instantiating a class and calling a method on the same line invalid?

Tags: php

This is what I'd like to do:

```
$app = (new Factory())->GetApp();
```

However, I get an "unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR" error.

To avoid this, I have to do:

```
$Factory = new Factory();
$app = $Factory->GetApp();
```

Why is this necessary?  I'm running PHP 5.2 if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly tautological answer, but it's because that's not supported in PHP 5.2.

However, it is in PHP 5.4 - see http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.other.php

> Added class member access on instantiation (e.g. (new foo)->bar())
>   support

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this:

```
class MyClass {

  public static function init(){
    return new self();
  }

  ....

}
```

which you can then use like this:

```
MyClass::init()->doStuff()->Whatever();
```

which is in my eyes a bit nicer, than using the

```
(new Myclass())->doStuff()->Whatever();
```